# how to edit or sketch the taken picture by using AVCaptureSession in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, camera

I am working on one application in which user have to capture the photo of the faults in building location. After capturing the photo user can comment below the photo as well as he can sketch the arrow or circle(for eg. paint software in windows computer) on the picture to show the fault.

There is one app on App store "Penultimate". I want similar kind of functions for my app.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can used AVIARY SDK to edit photo like you want in your app

Comment: Well, I checked the Aviary application on App store and it has paint feature. Let see how could aviary sdk work for me. Thank you very much Tapan

Comment: :P its paid sdk. Do you know any other one...Tapan

Comment: You can download AviarySDK from github, sorry but i don't have any link to download it, but i know that it is totally free, you just search and download it then i will provide code to implement it

Comment: I have followed this links "http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/" Which is cool and working.